# Python Calling a looped variable from a function

Tags: python, function, calling-convention

I've looked around for similar questions but they do not work since my code is slightly different.

I have a variable which is in a while loop which assigns a filename and i want to use this file name in a different function.

The problem is when I call the variable from another function; it repeats the `"Enter a file name"`

```
def save():
        file_name=loaddata()
        shutil.copyfile(file_name "CHECKED_v1.txt")
        print ("Saved Succesfully")
```

So I want to use the filename `"Enter the name of the file to open"` in the `savedata` function without it keep on looping

Comment: Everytime you call `loaddata()` the `input` function will be executed and there are no strange here

Comment: You should use a boolean flag where you only enter the loop in a certain condition, e.g.  `use_last_filename=True`

Answer (score 2):

You want the ability to pass the filename as an argument to your function.

You can do this:

```
def savedata(file_name=None):
    if not file_name:
        file_name = loaddata()
    shutil.copyfile(file_name "CHECKED_v1.txt")
    print ("Saved Succesfully")
```

And then you can either call `savedata()` and this will ask you to manually enter the file name, or you can call `savedata('/path/filename.txt')` and you won't be prompted for the file name.

Comment: It gets to the stage of `file_name=loaddata()` but then it calls load data again and it goes back to the step of it asking to open the file in a loop.

Comment: You need to call savedata with an argument to the function.